# Testing current location in Iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I have integrated the myAnnotationview custiomed api in to my project.And i have added some address on it.I want to test it from iphone simulator.Is it possible?How can i achieve it?Do i need to ON anything in Simulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is or what you hope to achieve. You can add a custom annotation to a specific location specifying the coordinate using CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( , );

If you are interested in your current address, use CLLocationManager for the specific location. On the simulator on a MKMapView your current location is always Infinite Loop at San Jose, California.